# Faster way to iterate through a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, iteration

Sample Table :
SAMPLE TABLE :

```
ACCOUNT_KEY                    SG         Total_sales
C9240000000000440             1.LOYAL++   84000.000
C9240000000000067           3.COMMITTED   35723.356
C9240000000000840         7.NEW JOINERS   26492.515
C9240000000000254       11.PROFESSIONAL   21598.651
C9240000000000027       11.PROFESSIONAL   21412.302
C9240000000000008          5.FRESH FOOD   16849.033
C9240000000000662       11.PROFESSIONAL   16005.060
C920000000000479             1.LOYAL++    15374.671
```

Can someone please help me speed up this code, actually the loop is taking a lot of time.

```
dataframe2 <- dataframe[order(-dataframe$Total_sales),]
dataframe2$ACCOUNT_KEY = as.factor(dataframe2$ACCOUNT_KEY)
dataframe2$SG = as.factor(dataframe2$SG)

rm(TG)
rm(CG)
summary(dataframe2)

CG = head(dataframe2,1)
dataframe2 = dataframe2[-1,]
TG = head(dataframe2,1)
dataframe2 = dataframe2[-1,]

j = 2
k = 2

for (i in 1 : nrow(dataframe2)) 
{
if (sum(TG$Total_sales) < sum(CG$Total_sales))
{
  
  TG[j,] = dataframe2[i,]
  j = j+1
}
else
{  
  CG[k,] = dataframe2[i,]
  k = k+1
}
}
```

I am trying to divide this dataframe into two dataframes TG and CG such that the sum of Total Sales is the same in both the tables.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Rahul. This question is about improving functional code, which is something that should be addressed at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) [rather than SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211788/code-review-vs-stackoverflow).

Comment: Avoid the loop.  Calculate the total value of sales.  Divide this by two.  Calculate the cumulative sum of sales for each row of your data.  Split your data at the row where the cumlative sum is greater than or equal to half the total.  You will need to decide how to handle the edge case where the inequality is strict and if you are happy to have unequal row counts in the two subsets.  And other issues you haven't defined.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
         arrange(Total_sales) %>% 
         mutate(GroupSales=cumsum(Total_sales)/sum(Total_sales) < 0.5)
split(df1, df1$GroupSales)
$`FALSE`
        ACCOUNT_KEY                     SG Total_sales GroupSales
7 C9240000000000067            3.COMMITTED    35723.36      FALSE
8 C9240000000000440              1.LOYAL++    84000.00      FALSE

$`TRUE`
        ACCOUNT_KEY                     SG Total_sales GroupSales
1  C920000000000479              1.LOYAL++    15374.67       TRUE
2 C9240000000000662        11.PROFESSIONAL    16005.06       TRUE
3 C9240000000000008           5.FRESH FOOD    16849.03       TRUE
4 C9240000000000027        11.PROFESSIONAL    21412.30       TRUE
5 C9240000000000254        11.PROFESSIONAL    21598.65       TRUE
6 C9240000000000840          7.NEW JOINERS    26492.51       TRUE
```

Unfortunately, we can't pipe the call to `split` because `split` isn't part of the tidyverse (so NSE doesn't apply) and `GroupSales` doesn't exist in the *original* data frame.  Of course, you could write your own wrapper function to get the pipe to work if you wanted to.

Check:

```
lapply(split(df1, df1$GroupSales), function(x) sum(x$Total_sales))
$`FALSE`
[1] 119723.4

$`TRUE`
[1] 117732.2
```

Note that, in this case, we get a *much* more even split between the two groups when we sort in ascending order than when we sort in descending order.  The latter gives

```
lapply(split(df1, df1$GroupSales), function(x) sum(x$Total_sales))
$`FALSE`
[1] 153455.6

$`TRUE`
[1] 84000
```

A more robust algorithm will necessarily be more complicated.