# How to partition into equal sum subsets in R?

Tags: r, statistics, data-wrangling

I have a dataset with a column, X1, of various values. I would like to order this dataset by the value of X1, and then partition into K number of equal sum subsets. How can this be accomplished in R? I am able to find quartiles for X1 and append the quartile groupings as a new column to the dataset, however, quartile is not quite what I'm looking for. Thank you in advance!

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1000,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df <- within(df, quartile <- as.integer(cut(X1, quantile(X1, probs=0:4/4), include.lowest=TRUE)))
```

Comment: How do you guarantee that the "equal sum subsets" will indeed have exactly equal sums.  If you can't guarantee an exact solution, what sort of approximation are you willing to live with?  Also, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73087550/faster-way-to-iterate-through-a-dataframe/73088681#73088681).

Comment: I see, that is a good point. I suppose I'd like the most optimal solution, so that the difference in sums is minimized. Or such that the groupings are somehow optimized to be as distinct as possible (i.e. low variance within and high variance between groups). I'm open to seeing other ways to accommodate for this as well though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this type of problem/algorithm has a name? I'm looking to use it for a specific application, but realize it may be a broader area of study?

Comment: See my answer to the question I linked to above.  For more sophisticated solutions, provide a more well-defined problem statement, some test data, and the expected output based on that test data.

Comment: I see, something rough will be sufficient for my use case.

Comment: "low variance within and high variance between groups" is close to a cluster analysis.  But a cluster analysis finds the global optimum, not the optimum constrained by equal group size/value.    I'm beginning to wonder if this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I was trying to answer your original question on what happens if you can't guarantee an exact solution. My response was that I am open to looking at different ways to accommodate for that, and that I'm open to a rough solution. I am looking to do exactly what I outlined in my post, not anything else that you're wondering about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rough solution (using `set.seed(47)` if you want to reproduce exactly). I calculate the proportion of the sum for each row, and do the `cumsum` of that proportion, and then `cut` that into the desired number of buckets.

```
library(dplyr)

n_groups = 10

df %>% arrange(X1) %>%
  mutate(
    prop = X1 / sum(X1),
    cprop = cumsum(prop),
    bins = cut(cprop, breaks = n_groups - 1)
  ) %>%
  group_by(bins) %>% 
  summarize(
    group_n = n(),
    group_sum = sum(X1)
  )
# # A tibble: 9 × 3
#   bins           group_n group_sum
#   <fct>            <int>     <int>
# 1 (-0.001,0.111]     322     54959
# 2 (0.111,0.222]      141     54867
# 3 (0.222,0.333]      111     55186
# 4 (0.333,0.444]       92     55074
# 5 (0.444,0.556]       80     54976
# 6 (0.556,0.667]       71     54574
# 7 (0.667,0.778]       66     55531
# 8 (0.778,0.889]       60     54731
# 9 (0.889,1]           57     55397
```

This could of course be simplified--you don't need to keep around the extra columns, just `mutate(bins = cut(cumsum(X1 / sum(X1)), breaks = n_groups - 1))` will add the `bins` column to the original data (and no other columns), and the `group_by() %>% summarize()` is just to diagnose the result.